# toPrecision is causing a data bind to fail to update

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, ecmascript-5

I am working on a UI mod for a game which uses HTML, CSS and JavaScript to render UI elements. This mod displays information on the total surface area of all the planets in a system. It achieves this through a function which calculates the total surface area, then passes this information to another function for formatting. Finally, a data bind is used to display this information in the UI.

```
  var formatedString = function (number) {
    var km2 = 1000000
    number = number / km2
    if (number < 1000) {
      return number.toPrecision(3)
    } else {
      return Math.floor(number)
    }
  };

  model.systemSurfaceArea = ko.computed(function () {
    var area = 0
    model.selection.system().planets().forEach(function (planet) {
      if (planet.generator && planet.generator.biom != 'gas') {
        area += 4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(planet.generator.radius, 2)
      }
    })
    return formatedString(area)
  })

  var url = 'coui://ui/mods/section_of_foreign_intelligence/section_of_foreign_intelligence.html'
  $.get(url, function (html) {
    console.log("Loaded html " + url);
    var $fi = $(html)
    $('#system-detail').append($fi)
    ko.applyBindings(model, $fi[0])
  })
```

```html
<span class="system" data-bind="text: $root.systemSurfaceArea"></span>k<sup>2</sup>
```

I have encountered a bug whereby for some systems the data bind is not being updated. I can see through use of the console that all calculations are being performed correctly, but the value on the screen remains unchanged. I have traced this back to the use of `toPrecision(3)`. When the value of precision is lower than 5, or when `Math.floor(number)` is called, the data-bind will not always update.

To provide an example: I have systems A, B and C. When I click the systems in the order A, B, C, I would expect to see the system sizes A, B, C. Yet what happens is I see A, B, B. Clicking in the order C, B, A gives me sizes C, C, A. In this instance B and C are failing, yet A is unaffected and always displays correctly.

I am at a loss as to why this might be and am hoping someone can help.

EDIT: I have found that removing the table formatting from the HTML removes the problem. I just don't understand why.

```html
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Surface Area:
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="system" data-bind="text: $root.systemSurfaceArea"></span>k<sup>2</sup>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Threat Level:
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="system" data-bind="text: $root.systemThreat"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Couldn't it be that B and C have the same value when rounded? KO will only update the layout if the underlying value changes. If that's not it, it'd be helpful if you could provide us with working code where the issue could be reproduced.

Comment: While looking into the issue just now, I found it appears to be related to the data-binds being within a table. Removing the table formatting resolves the issue.

Comment: @BrotherWoodrow they are 10.2 and 2.54 respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced my HTML table with divs and CSS table formatting and it has resolved my issue. I still don't understand *why* the HTML table broke things though, so if anyone has an answer I'll happily mark it up.

```html
  <div class="table">
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">Surface Area:</div>
      <div class="td"><span class="system" data-bind="text: $root.systemSurfaceArea"></span>k<sup>2</sup></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
      <div class="td">Threat Level:</div>
      <div class="td"><span class="system" data-bind="text: $root.systemThreat"></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```css
.table {
   display: table;
   }
.tr { 
  display: table-row; 
}
.td { 
  display: table-cell; 
}
```